# How would I get a list of 'friends' who have added my Facebook application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm really struggling with something that *should* be a simple matter: Showing a user of my Facebook app a list of their friends also using the app. Is there nothing built into the APIs to allow such a common request?

The only thing I can think of to do is to get the list of the user's friends, and then get all the users from *my* database who are in that list, and *then* fetch information for each of those facebook ids. But that seems an extremely roundabout way of doing things...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I've found to do this is to use FQL and a previously documented, but now undocumented field:

```
SELECT uid,name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=<user's uid>) AND is_app_user=1 ORDER BY name
```

The undocumented field is the user.is_app_user, which is listed in the [old documentation wiki](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/User_(FQL)) but not in the [shiny new docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user).  No idea if this means it'll be removed in the future, but there doesn't seem to be any other way to get this data with the new Graph API.

Just in-case you're still using the old REST API, you can also call the [friends.getAppUsers](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/friends.getAppUsers) method.

Comment: I didn't realize that parameter still existed. I guess I'll be using that.
Quick question though, how do I call an FQL query using the new PHP api?

I tried calling `$facebook->api('/fql.query?query=...')` but it told me "Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: fql.query" which I guess is because you're supposed to call that from api.facebook.com, as opposed to graph.facebook.com, but I'm unsure how to fix it.

Comment: Never mind, I found it.  `$facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => $query))`

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use Facebook's old REST API to do this by sending a GET request to: https://api.facebook.com/method/friends.getAppUsers

If you need JSON data back, then add the parameter `format=json`

You need an access token to do this. See the documentation here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/friends.getAppUsers/